# Deployed Access Web App connection string

Tags: sharepoint, office365-apps

I have an Access Web App that I created in Access 2013 and deployed on a sharepoint 365 online site. When I developed the web app, I could access the connection strings using Access 2013, but after I deployed it as an app on a different site, I no longer have access to the connection string. I've developed a separate application in Delphi that now needs to connect to the new deployed instance of the web app but I need the DB connection string to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've used Save for Deployment and locked the app then there is no way of getting at the connection information at the moment I'm afraid. Vote for the feature on Access User Voice and hopefully MS will do something about it!

Julian

Comment: Hi Julian. Yes, figured as much. What I eventually did was leave the app unlocked so I could access the connection string, but then hide the gear icon using some CSS. Added the line: .ms-siteactions-root {display: none !important;} to a custom CSS file and now my users can't download the app. Still a silly oversight by MS in my opinion.